# Datepicker not working in dynamically added row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

When a row is added dynamically in a table, I don't get the datepicker,time spinner or the validations working for the second row.

my code for adding a row...

```
function addRow(tableID){
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

  for(var i = 0;i<colCount;i++){

     var newccell = row.insertCell(i);
     newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[i].cells[i].innerHTML;

  }
}
```

and my code for the button is

```
<input type = "button" onclick = "addRow(tableID)" name="+" value="+" id="add">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

---

Add validation code using Event Delegation.

---

Update

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newccell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[i].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
    var $row = $(row);
    $row.find('input.sp').spinner(); //find element which you want to add spinner
    $row.find('input.dp').datepicker();//find element which you want to add datepicker
}
```

Comment: I don't think the question is about event delegation... it is about dynamic elements and widgets

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the plugins/widgets for dynamic elements once the elements are rendered to the dom

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newccell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[i].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }

    var $row = $(row);
    $row.find('input.spinner').spinner(){};//initialize spinner
    $row.find('input.datepicker').datepicker({});//iniitailze datepicker etc
}
```

use clone

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var $table = $('#' + tableID),
        $first = $table.find('tr').first();
    var $row = $first.clone().appendTo($table)
    $row.find('input.spinner').spinner() {};
    $row.find('input.datepicker').datepicker({});
}
```